# Odoo Inherit view can't set invisible attribute

Tags: odoo-13

I am odor newer.

I want to use the sale.order field and value to create a custom report by select some specific

field from sale.order.

I have created a custom model to inherit sale.order model.

And create a view to inherit view of sale.order.

Here is my code:

class SaleOrder(models.Model):

_inherit = 'sale.order'

```
<field name="name">Custom Sale Report</field> 

<field name="res_model">sale.order</field> 

<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
```

```
<field name="name">sale.order.inherited</field>

<field name="model">sale.order</field> 

<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_tree" /> 

<field name="mode">primary</field>

 <field name="arch" type="xml"> 

    <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="attributes"> 

      <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> 

    </xpath> </field> </record>
```

But I don't know why the invisible attribute is not working.

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<field name="name">sale.order.inherited</field>

<field name="model">sale.order</field> 

<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_tree" /> 
<field name="arch" type="xml"> 

    <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="replace"> 

      <field name="name" optional="hide"/>

    </xpath> 
    </field> 
    </record>
```

Comment: But may I ask why didn't use "<field name="mode">primary</field>"?
I found some document that attribute can modify the inherit view without change the raw view.
But when I use the "<field name="mode">primary</field>" , i always made the raw view changed.

Comment: @謝昀忻 You can read there.https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/field-name-mode-primary-field-can-anyone-explain-the-purpose-of-this-104612